# Is Debug.Assert obsolete if you write unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, assertions

Just like the question asks, is there a need to add Debug.Assert into your code if you are writing unit tests (which has its own assertions)? I could see that this might make the code more obvious without having to go into the tests, however it just seems that you might end up with duplicated asserts. It seems to me that `Debug.Assert` was helpful before unit-testing became more prevalent, but is now unnecessary. Or, am I not thinking of some use case?

Comment: I think this is answered in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18288/are-asserts-or-unit-tests-more-important

Comment: @BenC Thanks for the link. I liked Berin's answer relating Design-By-Contract. That actually clicked the most with me..and made me wonder why I didn't see that in the first  place :-p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assertions make assumptions explicit. Well-written unit tests do the same, but in an entirely different place.

Therefore, assertions, interspersed into the logic, help *document* the code and make it more understandable. This is how I use assertions. This is helpful in particular when implementing algorithms from theoretical descriptions, which usually offer the assertions as part of a correctness proof.

In a way, unit tests and assertions are two sides of the same coin: unit tests attempt to ensure correctness by trial, while assertions attempt to ensure it by proof.

Furthermore, assertions may help debug such algorithms because they offer sub-unit resolution, if you will. Unit tests on the other hand are *inherently* constrained to a coarser resolution. They can’t tell you anything about the internal state of an algorithm. Having small units helps but isn’t always feasible.

Comment: +1 but I'm not seeing how assertions are proofs. They are still only being tested on specific cases.

Comment: @Winston If the assertions are rigorous then they do constitute the complete proof. A [partial correctness proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correctness_%28computer_science%29) for an algorithm is formulated in assertions on the algorithm state. You do not assert specific cases, you (should, and easily can) provide generality.

Comment: best thing is Design by Contract though - in my opinion.

Comment: I've never seen assertions with sufficient rigor to constitute a proof.

Comment: More to the point, assertions are made generally, but they are only verified for specific cases. I'm still not seeing a connection to proofs.

Comment: @Winston I was talking (explicitly) about documentation, not verification. The documentation provided by assertions can constitute a formal proof (and I’ve used them as such). This purpose is distinct from their second purpose, checking the state for specific invocations of the algorithm.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 6):

Unit tests assert correctness for specific inputs (the test inputs).

Contract assertions (or debug assertions) assert correctness for any given input.

If you want your code to be safer then the combination between the two will produce better results.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already mentioned, a combination of assertions and unit tests will document your code better and help to ensure correctness, but they are used for different reasons: assertions verify the internal state of a codebase while unit tests verify the external behavior of a codebase.

Also keep in mind that assertions and unit tests can be executed separately as well as together. Here are a few scenarios:

- Building the code in the IDE and running it in `Debug` configuration will only execute assertions.
- Executing unit tests in `Debug` configuration will also execute assertions.
- Executing unit tests in `Release` configuration will not execute assertions.

Therefore, it helps to have assertions scattered throughout the codebase that will be executed in `Debug` configuration as well as unit tests that can be executed separately in either `Debug` or `Release` configuration.